# Reactjs which is the better way to use change handler

Tags: reactjs, onchange

So I know there are several ways to do this but I am wondering which is the better or more appropriate way to create a search bar component? Could you please explain why? I'm new to react and have seen tutorials and what not and everybody does there change handlers a little differently.

```
state = {
 term: '',
};

onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);

onChange(e) {
 console.log(e.target.value);
 this.setState({ term: e.target.value });
};

<input
 value={this.state.term}
 onChange={this.onChange}
/>
```

I feel this way could be better because it allows you to reuse the onChange handler for several different states.

```
state = {
 term: '',
};

onChange = name => e => {
 this.setState({ [name]: e.target.value });
};

<input
 value={this.state.term}
 onChange={this.onChange('term')}
/>
```

Comment: You have to define _better_ to get a good answer. IMO it's uncommon to have a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) bound to a property called `onChange` (which suggests an event listener). Something like `onChange(key, event) { this.setState(_ => ({ [key]: e.target.value})); }` seems pretty straightforward however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to reuse the `onChange` handler, the below code would be more appropriate and better too.

```
onChange = e => {
 this.setState({ 
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value 
 });
};

<input type="text" name="name" onChange={(e)=>this.onChange(e)} />
```