# Reduce lag of displaying value on textfeild when binding onChange event for getting value in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui, onchange

I have a **TextField(Material-UI)** for input, On the same page have two tables with a lot of values.
To get value entered in textField, I have used onChange event with **setState** like below.

The issue is where using this method, for every value change, calling **setState** in order to render the page for every value change. This leads to making slowness in displaying the value on the field when a user is entering values in fast. Below is my code snippet to use for this.

```
    <TextField
              onChange={this.onChange}
              className={classes.textField}
              label={Multilanguage.Translate(this.props.label)}
              autoFocus={true}                  
            />

onChange = (event) => {
    if (event.target.value != null) {
      this.setState({ serial: event.target.value });
    }
  }
```

How to avoid unnecessary rendering when changing in TextField? What is the good way to handle this?

Note my ReactJs version is 16.4.0

Comment: *avoid unnecessary rendering* I think this is already handled by React Virtual DOM

Comment: possibly a duplicate ,check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51683504/reactjs-which-is-the-better-way-to-use-change-handler/51683729#51683729

Comment: @Rajesh, But when I debug, render method is called, and I notice that value showing in textfeild is getting lag when typing in fast.

Comment: @karthik, I need an answer to eliminate the lag of showing value in textfeild when typing fast.

Comment: you can declare a global variable outside the class and update its value before the setState(but it's a bad practice).`setState` is a async method so it definitely takes some time to update

Answer (score 0):

Lagging usually happens when React is doing unnecessary work. By every setState your component and all of its children in the DOM get re-rendered. React doesn't update a component if its state or props has not changed, But even checking for whether or not it should re-render is a lot of computation that may lead to slowness.

I'd say add the following lifecycle method to all of your components. It eliminates unnecessary re-renders. The performance boost would be obvious.

```
shouldComponentUpdate = (nextProps, nextState) => {
    return shallowCompare(this, nextProps, nextState);
},
```

Changing Component to PureComponent is an alternative of the code above.

Comment: Thanks for your response, WIll check this and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hooks, `React.memo` should do the trick.
Find the expensive components that are actually unnecessarily rendering and wrap them in a `React.memo` HOC, like so ...

```
Import React, {memo}
...

const MyExpensiveComponent = (props) => {
...
render()
}

export default memo(MyExpensiveComponent)
```

If you are subscribing to a context (i.e useContext hook), you may encounter some issues, like I do. I found this post that is worth to read 
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15156#issuecomment-474590693

or read more about memo https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo